# Magento export products in Excel format without third party library

Tags: magento-1.9, products, export, format, product-grid

I am using Magento CE-1.9.2.x in my website.

Now I want `Catalog >> Manage Products >> Actions` select box to include the `Export Products to XLS` option, with only a custom controller and custom action in background to be able to export products to xls format.

I have seen `content-type` of `application/octet-stream` is allowed in `_prepareDownloadResponse()` function, how this can help me and also what should be column-separator for `xls` format ?

I want this with default Magento functions without the use of any third party libraries.

I have searched a lot on Google but couldn't find a reliable code block or post for this.

Hope anyone here can help me out.

Comment: The admin controllers you extend have the functions to generate excel files, you just need to call them. See core controllers for examples

Comment: I saw the core-controllers, but haven't been able to figure out the format and separator things, can you provide an example for xls generation ?

Answer (score 3):

.csv use "," seperated.

while .xls format uses tab seperated.

> so remove "," and replace with Tab or "\t".

**I hope this will help you.**

Answer (score 1):

The file generation isn't in controller the grid block is who performs such actions, so you should...

1. Add a massiveAction in the main form block (add the action option)
2. Add a controller action to route process/validate params (products selection) and instantiate right grid block
3. Create a grid block to filter, prepare columns and load the collection and then returns to controller to be exported.

You can check the reports/sales/orders/ structure to figure out how to do these steps.

I don't know how xls format works, but i'm pretty sure that you could find a xls library in Zend Framework. Remember that any CSV could be perfectly opened in excel and you can natively export products in that format.

> **Anyway** I have to say.. I don't thing that this would be a good idea due to complexity of catalog product entities. I strongly recommend to use another tool like import/export or data-flow profile to do that. If you have a couple of different attributes sets and export all products you could exceed the limit of joins that mysql can handle.